# Static variables declared outside of a class

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, variables, static

The [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com) framework has a horrible function [is_php()](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/source-function-is_php.html#44-55).

```
/**
* Determines if the current version of PHP is greater then the supplied value
*
* Since there are a few places where we conditionally test for PHP > 5
* we'll set a static variable.
*
* @access   public
* @param    string
* @return   bool    TRUE if the current version is $version or higher
*/
if ( ! function_exists('is_php'))
{
    function is_php($version = '5.0.0')
    {
        static $_is_php;
        $version = (string)$version;

        if ( ! isset($_is_php[$version]))
        {
            $_is_php[$version] = (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, $version) < 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }

        return $_is_php[$version];
    }
}
```

Notice that the variable `$_is_php` is defined `static`. This function is not defined in any class, so I don't see that the `static` definition is correct syntax, even if it (supposedly) does have the (supposed) intended effect of making the variable persist across function calls. I don't see this use mentioned in [the PHP documentaion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). **Where is this non-class usage of the `static` keyword documented?** Is this an 'undocumented feature' of PHP, and possibly not supported and therefore should not be relied upon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` variables are defined and documented in the [variable scope manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static).

The meaning is slightly different than the `static` keyword which declares class properties. In this case, `static` variables simply keep their value, even across function calls when they should have gone out of scope, yet without exposing their scope to the outside world.

Comment: Hey there, long time no see! Thank you, the man page that you link to sums it up, I wonder why Google does not return it when searching for PHP static.